# Conditional search

Tags: support

Is there a way to search for posts containing (text1 OR text2) AND text3?

**Edit for clarity:** It would be the same as a join of the searches `text1 AND text3` and `text2 AND text3`

There probably is, just it is not on the search tips page, and I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The best option I can find is using `body:` (posts with specific words in the body 
)

Example: `body: text1 text2 text3`

Separating them like that will include all 3 things. If you want different specific lines, you could do something like:

`body:"My Name is" "Simon" "Sheehan"`

This is as close as you can get. What you are asking is not possible within our search system

Comment: But If I don't care if it contains "Simon" then my search results will be limited.

Comment: @soandos It's an example. Im saying you can do multiple phrases. By putting all 3 in, you get the search results of doing 3 searches, but now in one

Comment: I don't think this does what I want.

Comment: @soandos I feel your question is vague then, could you expand more?

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: @soandos thats basically what I've said then. By what I can understand, my solution fits your wants.

Comment: I do not want all three included. I want at least two out of three included.

Comment: @soandos then only type in two of the three. Modify it to fit your needs. Add and remove as you want

Comment: perhaps it would be clearer if I said it as follows: I want text3 and at least one of text1 and text2. Your solution does not do that.

Comment: @soandos then you're asking too much out of our search system.